# how can i make this page "flexible"

Tags: html, css

I am sorry for the bad wording but I am not sure how to call it.
I have this page and if you adjust the window size everything should get smaller so everything still fits in the window.
How can I achieve this?
I am very new to HTML and CSS.
The whole code is written by me.
The CSS is normally in it's own file but i decided to put it together so I don't need to post two different files.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
}

#box {
  background-color: white;
  height: 750px;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 35px auto auto auto;
}

#header {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  height: 100px;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

#logo {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 75px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 12.5px;
  left: 4.5%;
}

#user-count {
  text-align: center;
}

#main {
  background-color: rgb(212, 212, 212);
  height: 525px;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 525px;
  width: 700px;
  position: relative;
}

#right {
  background-color: rgb(98, 0, 255);
  height: 525px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

#left-content {
  background-color: rgb(0, 146, 146);
  height: 100%;
  width: 675px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 6.25px;
}

#right-content {
  background-color: rgb(53, 0, 138);
  height: 100%;
  width: 475px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 6.25px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#login {
  background-color: rgb(149, 83, 255);
  height: 45%;
  width: 100%;
}

#news {
  background-color: rgb(83, 48, 139);
  height: 55%;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <header id="header">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <nav id="user-count">x user online</nav>
  </header>
  <main id="main">
    <div id="left">
      <div id="left-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div id="right-content">
        <div id="login"></div>
        <div id="news"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>This is the footer <br> Copyright head shoulders knees and toes</footer>
</div>
```

If you would do something completely different, tell me. I am open to learn new stuff but you need to explain how and why.

Comment: It's called "responsive", since the website will adjust for smaller screens automatically. Also, I find it rather difficult to help you, since you didn't specify what you wanted it to look like on smaller screens. In other words, this might be a bit too much for a question on stack overflow

Comment: If you want a flexible page you must stop using inflexible pixel sizes. Use percentage values instead. Then do a lot more research.

Answer (score 0):

They Call Flexible is `Responsive`
You can using a CSS Framework for build up `Responsive Page`
I have example from `BULMA CSS`
**Check on Snippet**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  // Get all "navbar-burger" elements
  var $navbarBurgers = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger'), 0);

  // Check if there are any nav burgers
  if ($navbarBurgers.length > 0) {

    // Add a click event on each of them
    $navbarBurgers.forEach(function ($el) {
      $el.addEventListener('click', function () {

        // Get the target from the "data-target" attribute
        var target = $el.dataset.target;
        var $target = document.getElementById(target);

        // Toggle the class on both the "navbar-burger" and the "navbar-menu"
        $el.classList.toggle('is-active');
        $target.classList.toggle('is-active');

      });
    });
  }

});
```

```css
.navbar-item.is-mega {
  position: static;
}
.navbar-item.is-mega-menu-title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: .375rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar ">
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <a class="navbar-item" href="http://bulma.io">
      <img src="http://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" alt="Bulma: a modern CSS framework based on Flexbox" width="112" height="28">
    </a>

    <a class="navbar-item is-hidden-desktop" href="https://github.com/jgthms/bulma" target="_blank">
      <span class="icon" style="color: #333;">
        <i class="fa fa-github"></i>
      </span>
    </a>

    <a class="navbar-item is-hidden-desktop" href="https://twitter.com/jgthms" target="_blank">
      <span class="icon" style="color: #55acee;">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
      </span>
    </a>

    <div class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="navMenubd-example">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="navMenubd-example" class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-start">
      <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
        <a class="navbar-link  is-active" href="/documentation/overview/start/">
          Docs
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-dropdown ">
          <a class="navbar-item " href="/documentation/overview/start/">
            Overview
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/modifiers/syntax/">
            Modifiers
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics/">
            Columns
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/layout/container/">
            Layout
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/form/general/">
            Form
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/elements/box/">
            Elements
          </a>

          <a class="navbar-item is-active" href="http://bulma.io/documentation/components/breadcrumb/">
            Components
          </a>

          <hr class="navbar-divider">
          <div class="navbar-item">
            <div>
              <p class="is-size-6-desktop">
                <strong class="has-text-info">0.5.1</strong>
              </p>

              <small>
                <a class="bd-view-all-versions" href="/versions">View all versions</a>
              </small>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable is-mega">
        <div class="navbar-link flex">
          Blog <span class="tag is-info ml-2">Hover here<span>
        </div>
        <div id="blogDropdown" class="navbar-dropdown " data-style="width: 18rem;">
          <div class="container is-fluid">
            <div class="columns">
              <div class="column">
                <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title">Sub Menu Title</h1>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">
                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">
                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">
                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title">Sub Menu Title</h1>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">

                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="/documentation/overview/start/">
                  Overview
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/modifiers/syntax/">
                  Modifiers
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics/">
                  Columns
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title">Sub Menu Title</h1>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">
                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">
                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/2017/08/03/list-of-tags/">
                  <div class="navbar-content">
                    <p>
                      <small class="has-text-info">03 Aug 2017</small>
                    </p>
                    <p>New feature: list of tags</p>
                  </div>
                </a>

              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title">Sub Menu Title</h1>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="/documentation/overview/start/">
                  Overview
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/modifiers/syntax/">
                  Modifiers
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics/">
                  Columns
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/documentation/layout/container/">
                  Layout
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <hr class="navbar-divider">
          <div class="navbar-item">
            <div class="navbar-content">
              <div class="level is-mobile">
                <div class="level-left">
                  <div class="level-item">
                    <strong>Stay up to date!</strong>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="level-right">
                  <div class="level-item">
                    <a class="button bd-is-rss is-small" href="http://bulma.io/atom.xml">
                      <span class="icon is-small">
                        <i class="fa fa-rss"></i>
                      </span>
                      <span>Subscribe</span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
        <div class="navbar-link">
          More
        </div>
        <div id="moreDropdown" class="navbar-dropdown ">
          <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/extensions/">
            <div class="level is-mobile">
              <div class="level-left">
                <div class="level-item">
                  <p>
                    <strong>Extensions</strong>
                    <br>
                    <small>Side projects to enhance Bulma</small>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="level-right">
                <div class="level-item">
                  <span class="icon has-text-info">
                    <i class="fa fa-plug"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/expo/">
        <span class="bd-emoji"></span> &nbsp;Expo
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item " href="http://bulma.io/love/">
        <span class="bd-emoji">❤️</span> &nbsp;Love
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-end">
      <a class="navbar-item is-hidden-desktop-only" href="https://github.com/jgthms/bulma" target="_blank">
        <span class="icon" style="color: #333;">
          <i class="fa fa-github"></i>
        </span>
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item is-hidden-desktop-only" href="https://twitter.com/jgthms" target="_blank">
        <span class="icon" style="color: #55acee;">
          <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
        </span>
      </a>
      <div class="navbar-item">
        <div class="field is-grouped">
          <p class="control">
            <a class="bd-tw-button button" data-social-network="Twitter" data-social-action="tweet" data-social-target="http://bulma.io" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Bulma: a modern CSS framework based on Flexbox&hashtags=bulmaio&url=http://bulma.io&via=jgthms">
              <span class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
              </span>
              <span>
                Tweet
              </span>
            </a>

          </p>
          <p class="control">
            <a class="button is-primary" href="https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/archive/0.5.1.zip">
              <span class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
              </span>
              <span>Download</span>
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<section class="hero is-primary">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title">
        Bulma.io with Full Width Menu (Mega Menu)
      </h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle">
        Hover over Blog
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column is-4">
          <div class="notification is-light is-link">Hi! <br />I recently launched this project focused on developers. I hope you will find it useful.</div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <figure class="image is-fullwidth">
              <img src="https://codedmails.com/images/banner-codedemails.png" alt="Coded Mails">
            </figure>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p class="title is-4">Codedmails Free</p>
            <p class="subtitle is-6"><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/codedmails">@codedmails</a></p>

            <div class="content">

              <p>Ready to use <strong>60+ HTML email templates and themes </strong>for startups and developers for free.</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <footer class="card-footer">
            <a href="https://codedmails.com" target="_blank" class="card-footer-item">Visit Codedmails</a>
          </footer>
        </div>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have several options:
Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/
Bootstrap is developed to be mobile first and uses breakpoints for our layouts and interfaces.